# Elasticsearch Index Data giving wrong results in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a full text search using Elasticsearch for my react web app but it is not returning all the results on query. I think I'm doing some mistake in my bulk method but I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong.
My code is:

```
// Declare variable to contain body of JSON data for loading to ElasticSearch

                    let br = [];

// Function to create body for loading to ElasticSearch
                    function create_bulk (bulk_request) {
                        let obj;

                        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                            obj = res[i];
                            // Insert header of record
                            bulk_request.push({index: {_index: 'tweet', _type: 'tweet', _id: i+1}});
                            bulk_request.push(obj);
                        }
                        return bulk_request;
                    }

// Call function to get body for loading
                    create_bulk(br);

// Standard function of ElasticSearch to use bulk command
                    client.bulk(
                        {
                            body : br
                        }, function (err, resp) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });

                    client.search({
                        index: 'tweet',
                        type: 'tweet',
                        body: {
                            query: {
                                match: {"text" : "new york" }
                            },
                        }
                    },function (error, response,status) {
                        if (error){
                            console.log("search error: "+error)
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("--- Response ---");
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log("--- Hits ---");
                            response.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit){
                                console.log(hit);
                            })
                        }
                    });
```

Data Sample which is an array of JSON data:

```
{date: "2014-06-04 11:30:07", text: "New York Today: Honoring our Civil Servants t.co/Lhz9fgt2FW", user_id: "nytimes "}
```

Comment: Between your bulk call and your search call, you need to call refresh to make sure all indexed data is available for search.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @Val It got indexed fine as it is returning 10 results which is the limit I guess. Can you please tell me how to change that limit if you have any idea about it from node? I tried it from localhost and after changing the size it is returning all the results.

Comment: Yes, simply add `size: 100` in your search call

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to include all search? If not then I'll use some huge number.

Comment: By default, you can use up to 10000, then you'll need to use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your bulk call and your search call, you need to call refresh to make sure all indexed data is available for search.

```
                client.bulk(
                    {
                        refresh: true,            <--- add this
                        body : br
                    }, function (err, resp) {
                        console.log(err);

                        client.search({...})      <--- and make your search call only when the bulk returns

                    });
```